# how to set the path of a command

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell, couchbase

I am trying to install elasticsearch plugin from couchbase, and as written in this official [installation guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/elastic/install-plugin.html), I have to do this:

```
bin/plugin -install transport-couchbase -url \
http://packages.couchbase.com.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/elastic-search-adapter/2.0.0/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase-2.0.0.zip
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> the system can't find the specified path

[image]

Comment: did you try to put the url in quatation?

Comment: @eyalb I will try now, but should I put the quatation including the `\` which is before `http` or not please?

Comment: Try removing the `\ ` and putting the whole command on one line.

Comment: This looks like PowerShell, not cmd. That's good, but you should specify which you're using.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I found the solution and wrote it as an answer

Comment: @DavidPostill I found what was wrong and wrote it as an answer bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error myself, it was that i was putting bin in the java home path. when i put the java home path without bin, it works

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to download the plugin and the install it from you location.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html

if you use --url it will download it if it is on  download.elastic.co

"The plugins will be automatically downloaded in this case from download.elastic.co, and in case they don’t exist there, from maven (central and sonatype)."

Comment: i followed your answer as this:

`C:\elasticsearch-1.3.9\elasticsearch-1.3.9> bin/plugin -install transport-couchbase -url "C:\elasticsearch-transport-
couchbase-2.0.0"
The system cannot find the path specified.`
that is what i did, and the same error message, do you think i made a mistake in my command please?

Comment: i found the solution and wrote it as an answer bellow.